# Catch cannot catch type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Exception'

Tags: vb.net, exception, outlook

I have a program in VB.Net that receives mails from Outlook, extracts attachments and inserts the attachments into a table through a query. I would like to put the query/queries in a Try/Catch block, but cannot do so as Outlook exceptions cannot be caught, and it gives me an error, and unless I put a very specific exception, I cannot catch it. Is there a workaround?

**Edit:**

```
    Try

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Exception is underlined and when I hover on it, it says: "Catch cannot catch type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Exception' because it is not in 'System.Exception' or a class that inherits from 'System.Exception'". This is affecting all my other code which I'd like to put into a Try/Catch block. What to do?

Comment: What makes you think that Outlook exceptions cannot be caught?

Comment: @Heinzi: Please read my edited question. Should be ok now I guess.

Comment: Thanks, it's clear now. I've added another answer (and removed my old one). I also took the liberty to change the title of your question, so that it more accurately summarizes the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I see the problem now.

When you write `Exception`, VB reads `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Exception` (probably because you have an `Import Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` statement at the top of your code file).

You need to tell VB explicitly that you mean `System.Exception`:

```
Try
    ...
Catch ex As System.Exception
    ...
End Try
```

(Since `M.O.I.O.Exception` is not a .net exception but simply an Outlook COM class that happens to be called `Exception`, there'd be no point in trying to `Catch` it.)

Comment: The real question, of course, is why you're catching `System.Exception` in the first place. You're not going to be able to handle most of the exceptions derived from that base class, so there's little point in catching them.

Comment: Good catch, another reason not to bluntly import Microsoft.Office.Stuff

Comment: @Cody Gray: I'm not gonna handle them, just maintain a log of them. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is not such thing as "XXX exceptions cannot be caught". It probably has a type that you don't known. You should read documentation for the library that you use and find the type of the exception.

Edit: To answer the subject: if you want to catch all exception except one, you should catch all exception and throw again that exception.

Comment: Nope. The solution is never to catch and rethrow exceptions for no reason. Figure out the exception you want to catch, and catch that one.

Comment: The subject was "How to catch all exceptions except one". And for this was my response...

Comment: So, you neither read the entire question, nor provided the correct answer. For the record, in VB.NET you would simply write: `Catch ex As Exception When Not (TypeOf ex Is CustomException)`. As I mentioned before, catching all exceptions and rethrowing one is not the correct answer to any question, much less this one.